# Map a key to start a program

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

I haven't seen this question, I would love to map the start button on my keyboard and desktop to open an application instead of the Windows start menu. I currently use XLaunchpad as my start menu and I'd rather have that start as I really rarely use the start menu now.

I have Windows 10 Pro on a Surface Pro 3

Comment: @Burgi I have just read up on it and did a lot of research. The Surface Pro has a MS app that disables the button, but nothing to remap.

Answer (score 0):

You can't map an individual key to launch a program, at least not using anything built into Windows, and even if you could, it would be a bad idea. The Windows key is used for a *LOT* more than just opening Start (use it in a chord with the number row, the arrow keys, the Tab key, at least half the letter keys, etc.; it's part of a ton of shortcuts).

However, you can create your own shortcut chords, no problem. One option is to pin the programs to the Taskbar, then use the Win+ chord to launch the relevant program (for example, by default in Win10, Win+1 will launch Edge because it's the first thing on the Taskbar). Otherwise, you can try the "Shortcut Key" field in the Properties window of a shortcut. That field is restricted in what chords you can use - Ctrl+Alt+ is the usual - but is still more flexible and isn't dependent on how your Taskbar is laid out.

Comment: Thank you very much — I didn't think about all of that.  But if I could just change what the Windows button does on my Surface Pro — The hardware button on the side of the device